# Typescript: Import value from object

Tags: typescript

Lets say I have a typescript file `environment.ts` where I export

```
export const environment = {
    host: localhost:8080,

    // more keys/values
}
```

Lets say I have another file `url.ts` where I want to import the environment object.

```
import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
```

Which works fine. I could do there something like

```
const host = environment.host
```

**Question:**

But, is there any way to just import the `host` value directly?

Comment: are you working with cli? and exactly, what do you mean with "import directly"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of exporting a toplevel object named environment you could export each value separately

```
export const host = 'localhost:8080';
export const foo = 'bar';
```

and then import them like this

```
import { host, foo } from 'environments/environment'
```

or import them all like this

```
import * as environment from 'environments/environment'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with angular cli, you could modify your `.angular-cli.json` file like this:

```js
{
  "defaults": {
    "serve": {
      "port": 8080,
      "host": "yourHost"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was asking for typescript in general.